# psycopg - Error while connecting to PostgreSQL tuple index out of range

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

First, thanks for your time!

I'm trying to use psycopg to run a sql on pgadmin but getting the following error:

```
Error while connecting to PostgreSQL tuple index out of range
```

The code:

```py
two_list = []

for x in range(1,10000):
    single_two = (sheet.cell(row=x, column=1).value)
    if single_two == None:
        break
    else:
        two_list.append(single_two[4:])

two_list = [int(i) for i in two_list]

  finalsql.execute("""SELECT 
                        CONCAT('CWO-',i.issuenum) as "TWO ID", i.summary, c.stringvalue as "Title ID", SUBSTRING(a.actionbody,22,11) as "MWO ID", a.created as "TWO created date"
                    FROM
                        jiraissue i,
                        customfieldvalue c,
                        jiraaction a
                    WHERE 
                    i.issuenum = ANY(%s)
                    AND 
                    i.id = c.issue
                    AND 
                    c.customfield = '10280'
                    AND 
                    i.id = a.issueid
                    AND 
                    a.actionbody like '%Content From: Video:%';""", (two_list,))
```

The same code works with a less complex sql:

```py
finalsql.execute("""SELECT creator FROM jiraissue WHERE issuenum = ANY(%s);""", (two_list,))
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Check that `%C` isn't being treated as another `%s` placeholder

Comment: Ouch! That's excellent! Thanks a lot for the help!!!!!!!!!! Cheers!!!